# Search stack components with Nutch

Tags: mongodb, nutch

I'm trying to understand the difference between Nutch 1.x and Nutch 2.x if I'm simply trying to use Nutch to crawl a couple hundred websites and then index the data to Elasticsearch v2.3.0

From what I understand, it seems the main difference is that Nutch 2.x can use multiple backends (Elasticsearch, MongoDB, HBase, Cassandra?, etc) to store the data.

However, if I don't have a need for multiple backends (just want to index the data to ES) then do I need to even worry about Nutch 2.x?

What would be some of the use cases for Nutch 2.x? Why would a search application using Nutch 2.x need multiple backends - Elasticsearch and MongoDB - for example? What kind of application would need Nutch 2.x to send data to multiple backends?

I have Nutch 1.x installed, configured and crawling ... just wandering if I'm missing something here with 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the bigest difference between the two brances is that 2.x offers multiple storages thanks to Apache Gora, but is also a rewrite with a deeper change in architecture around the same Map/Reduce idea (they both run on top of hadoop). But the 2.x branch is more focused on a "big table" architecture with the abstraction provided by Gora.

You can watch this video with has some more info about the differences between Nutch 1.x and 2.x (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyHPBtRlo80).

The hability to have multiple "copies" of your data in several storages is not to be taken lightly, at the end each storage serve its purpose and there is no "silver bullet" that will solve all your problems. For instance if you don't do backups of your segments, you could use some other DB additionally to Solr/ES to keep a long term backup of your data, and in any case being able to recreate your index by pulling data from that database.

In the end, if you need it you could use Nutch 2.x, if not I strongly suggest using Nutch 1.x (and you're using it) because to this point Nutch 1.x still offers more features out-of-the-box that Nutch 2.x and is more spread. And although Nutch 2.x is getting improvements all the time, last time, last time I checked Nutch 1.x was performing better that 2.x.